# Block tags before table

Tags: html, html-table, block

I have a problem with block level tags as being before the table, instead of inside tr, as I put them.

[image]

And the code:

[image]

Either I use div or p, they react the same

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wht would you add a block level element inside a table? Replace the `<div>` with a `<tr>` and it should work:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            ...
        </td>
        <td>
            ...
        </td>
        <td class="your-class">
            Your text
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If the text needs to be be under the input field, you can add another row:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            ...
        </td>
        <td>
            ...
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="your-class">
            Your text
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your second example isn't working as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/CristianAlexandru92/uvt0vcfy/ I want that text to be 100% width of whole previous <tr>. How could I accomplish that?

Comment: It might work when you add the `<div>` underneath the `<table>`

Comment: Yah, it does the same as I edited the post, adding colspan to the 2nd row in that td